# Images in rich text area

Tags: ee2, image, richtext

In the ee control panel I have a textarea(rich text) that I use for writing some news articles. These articles include some images in them and I continually have to write the HTML for inserting images. Is there a way to instead of having to write the HTML myself, adding I.E a button next to the "link" button to insert an image?

I'm new to ee so an easy solution is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use an addon custom field type that is better suited to your needs. This is the one I use:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam

It gives you more of a WYSIWYG-style field input, and is much easier to work with for someone looking to avoid code for whatever reason. There is a few others like Wygwam, so I recommend poking around the devot-ee.com site. It's a major hub of ExpressionEngine addons.

Installing addons is generally the same for most addons, but there is no official guide; the addon should come with instructions. But if you have trouble, comment on my answer and I'll write up some instructions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you :D

Comment: No problem! Like I said, if you run into trouble, comment on my answer and I'll try to help you get it sorted out.